# I am new to SQLAlchemy. I am trying to query and manipulate a database, but I get a "removed In 20" warning?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine, Table, Column, Float, ForeignKey, Integer, String, MetaData
)

# executing the instructions from our localhost "chinook" db
db = create_engine("postgresql:///chinook", future=True)

meta = MetaData(db)

# create variable for "Artist" table
artist_table = Table(
    "Artist", meta,
    Column("ArtistId", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("Name", String)
)

# create variable for "Album" table
album_table = Table(
    "Album", meta,
    Column("AlbumId", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("Title", String),
    Column("ArtistId", Integer, ForeignKey("artist_table.ArtistId"))
)

# create variable for "Track" table
track_table = Table(
    "Track", meta,
    Column("TrackId", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("Name", String),
    Column("AlbumId", Integer, ForeignKey("album_table.AlbumId")),
    Column("MediaTypeId", Integer, primary_key=False),
    Column("GenreId", Integer, primary_key=False),
    Column("Composer", String),
    Column("Milliseconds", Integer),
    Column("Bytes", Integer),
    Column("UnitPrice", Float)
)

# making the connection
with db.connect() as connection:

    # Query 1 - select all records from the "Artist" table
    select_query = artist_table.select()

results = connection.execute(select_query)
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

```
codeany@9d5f3c4539c4:/workspaces/postgres-tutorial$ python3 sql-expression.py
/workspaces/postgres-tutorial/sql-expression.py:8: RemovedIn20Warning: Deprecated API features detected! These feature(s) are not compatible with SQLAlchemy 2.0. To prevent incompatible upgrades prior to updating applications, ensure requirements files are pinned to "sqlalchemy<2.0". Set environment variable SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20=1 to show all deprecation warnings.  Set environment variable SQLALCHEMY_SILENCE_UBER_WARNING=1 to silence this message. (Background on SQLAlchemy 2.0 at: https://sqlalche.me/e/b8d9)
  meta = MetaData(db)

    raise exc.ResourceClosedError("This Connection is closed")
sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This Connection is closed
```

Comment: When something says it's a warning instead of an error, you should take it at its word and not assume that the warning is the cause of any subsequent error (but investigate those errors independently, as an unrelated item).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the *warning* mentioned in the question title is usage of the option `future=True`:

```
db = create_engine("postgresql:///chinook", future=True)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.future), that option is deprecated:

> The `create_engine.future` parameter will be deprecated in a subsequent 2.x release and eventually removed.

and

> **Changed in version 2.0**: All [Engine](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine) objects are “future” style engines and there is no longer a `future=False` mode of operation.

To make the warning go away, you can just change it to:

```
db = create_engine("postgresql:///chinook")
```

That warning is only informational, and won't break your script. The script errors later because of an unrelated issue in the code: fix the indentation under the with-statement, as described in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77560002/674039).

Answer (score 0):

Are you running `execute` outside the `with` block ?  It isn't clear from your code.

Execute should be called within the `with` block.

```py
#...

with db.connect() as connection:
    # Query 1 - select all records from the "Artist" table
    select_query = artist_table.select()
    results = connection.execute(select_query)
    for result in results:
        print(result)
```